# What is Honda Coolant?

Tags: honda, civic, coolant, cooling-system

My 2000 Honda Civic 1.6 Aerodeck is getting a little low on coolant, and so needs a top-up.

The question is - what do I put in?

The manual rather unhelpfully says "use Honda coolant", but doesn't tell me what that is. Google doesn't either, but tells me that it is either blue or green depending on whether it is "type 1" or "type 2".

The local motor factors says it should be OAT (red - Organic Acid Technology). The coolant currently in there is blue. Is there an easy way to tell if the current coolant is the Honda-branded stuff, or if someone in the past has put MEG (traditional blue coolant - Methanol Ethylene Glycol) in there instead - in which case I don't want to mix it with OAT...

Or should I just flush the lot just to be safe?

EDIT: Looking at an old quesiton on here [[link]](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/1135/is-prestone-all-makes-all-models-coolant-really-compatible-with-all-models?rq=1), I find a link to a US Amazon page suggesting the Honda stuff is MEG - completely at odds with what the shop told me... Can anyone confirm this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Honda coolant is 50/50 prediluted, non-silicate/non-borate, type 2 ethylene glycol based coolant (I know this because I just snagged a bottle out of my basement and copied that off the back label, shown below).

[image: Honda Genuine coolant label]

Comment: Thanks - that definitely won't mix with the OAT the local shop's computer listed then!