# Do I need to use Genuine Honda Coolant?

Tags: honda, coolant

I have a 2003 Honda Accord. 
Do I need to use Genuine Honda All Season Antifreeze/Coolant Type 2? The manual says the above is a premix of 50/50 antifreeze and water.

It also said that I can temporarily use a major-brand non-silicate high quality coolant for aluminium engines.

It warns that if I use non-Honda coolant, it can result in corrosion causing the cooling system to malfunction or fail.

Is this true? If I can use other coolant permanently what would that be?

Comment: Nowadays almost all car companies make similar claims.  This question https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/7229/22368 has an answer with a rundown of what exactly the "honda" coolant is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

News flash, Honda doesn't make anti-freeze. :D

You can use any non-silicate coolant meant for aluminium engines. Go to your local auto parts store, they'll show you which ones they have.

The most important thing is to thoroughly flush your cooling system first to make sure there is no trace of the previous coolant. Incompatible coolants can cause deposits inside your cooling system.

Given the age of the vehicle, I recommend that after you drain your cooling system, fill it up with a household cleaner that dissolves calcium, lime and rust deposits. Fill up the system completely with that stuff, run the engine to temperature, then turn on the blower to max heat and let it run a few minutes more, give the cleaner time to do it's thing. Then drain completely and fill the system back up with your favourite coolant.

Answer (score 0):

There are other coolant brands such as Prestone, Aisin... made specific for Japanese and European cars include Honda.  Most of these are not sold on department stores but from auto parts store or online order.

Answer (score 0):

Use any non silicate coolant, just try to avoid mixing colors as that’s what helps to clog your heater core. I’ve seen the zerex blue coolant for Honda and Nissan at Walmart recently